# Is Google chart support dynamoDB directly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, timescaledb, react-google-charts

I am working on google chart data visualization tool. And I know that Google charts being able to use any SQL database as data source. But as dynamoDB is noSql database, and as per customer requirements they want to use dynamoDB as a data source. I want to know whether Google chart support query dynamoDB directly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way from Google Chart to support connecting to DynamoDb as a data source, but you can develop one on your own using the information [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/implementing_data_source).

AWS DynamoDB is a schema-less, NoSQL key-value store. Primary keys are defined either by a single hash key or by a combined hash and range key. The database can be accessed through a REST API call which exposes the following 3 operations for reading: GetItem, Query and Scan. More developer information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Using.API.html).

So maybe you want to build DynamoDB queries for the charts and then execute them via APIs to fetch the results. You can do this on your server-side where your traditional data source connections lives to set up the connection with DynamoDb.